# Select the maximal item from collection, by some criterion

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, extension-methods

i am new to .net 3.5.
I have a collection of items:

```
IList<Model> models;
```

where

```
class Model
{
    public string Name
    {
       get;
       private set;
    }
}
```

I would like to get the element, which has the longest name's length.
I tried

```
string maxItem = models.Max<Model>(model => model.Name.Length);
```

but it of course returns the maximum length (and I need a `Model` object). I know there is a way of doing this using the extension methods but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it to work. Maybe there's a better way, I'm not sure:

```
    decimal de = d.Max(p => p.Name.Length);
    Model a = d.First(p => p.Name.Length == de);
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it has to go through the list twice. That *may* be very expensive (or require buffering of a stream of data). It's nicer to be able to do the whole thing in one pass where possible.

Comment: If you're writing library code that will be used in unknown contexts, Jon is right.  If you know the context, you can know if two passes will be expensive or not.  I'd write `d.OrderBy(p => p.Name.Length).First()` if I knew the context.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't a built-in way of doing this, unfortunately - but it's really easy to write an extension method to do it.

It was in [one of my very first blog posts](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2005/10/02/a-short-case-study-in-linq-efficiency.aspx), in fact... note that there's a better implementation in one of the comments. I'll move it into the body if I get time.

EDIT: Okay, I have a slightly abbreviated version - it just returns the maximal element, using the given selector. No need to do a projection as well - do that once afterwards if you need to. Note that you could remove the constraint on `TValue` and use `Comparer<TValue>.Default` instead, or have an overload which allows the comparison to be specified as another parameter.

```
public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                             Func<TSource, TValue> selector)
    where TValue : IComparable<TValue>
{
    TValue maxValue = default(TValue);
    TSource maxElement = default(TSource);
    bool gotAny = false;

    foreach (TSource sourceValue in source)
    {
        TValue value = selector(sourceValue);
        if (!gotAny || value.CompareTo(maxValue) > 0)
        {
            maxValue = value;
            maxElement = sourceValue;
            gotAny = true;
        }
    }
    if (!gotAny)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("source is empty");
    }
    return maxElement;
}
```

Sample use: (note type inference):

```
string maxName = models.MaxBy(model => model.Name.Length).Name;
```

Comment: i'm afraid models.Max(model => model.Name.Length) returns int (length) no a Model so you can't use it like this (i mean the last line)

Comment: @agnieszka: That's using the built-in Max method, not the one I've given in the answer. To make it clearer, you could rename the new one to "MaxElement". Editing answer to reflect this.

Comment: What happens if you have a set with the comparison value multiple times: i.e. {5, 3, 5, 2}. Element 0 will be returned if my understanding is correct. But what makes element 0 more special than element 2 which has the same value... maybe returning a list of the things with the max value would help?

Comment: imo it's lame the built-in Max<> function doesn't work like this naturally--wouldn't that be better/more intuitive?

Comment: The built-in Enumerable.Max() is just broken.  What it does today could be written as "models.Max(model => model.Name.Length).Select(model => model.Name);" if Max() was written the right way.  (The justification is that it handles both single- and multiple- result cases)

Comment: Or you can write "models.Select(model => model.Name).Max()" with a fixed Max() to get the behavior that Max() does today.  I think that's what I meant. :-)

Comment: You could use the name MaxBy, just like OrderBy.

Comment: @Jay: I completely agree. I'm amazed that it's been done in the less flexible way.

Comment: @Jennifer: I think in *most* use cases you probably don't mind which gets returned, and it's more convenient to return a single element. There could always be a differently-named method with your suggested behaviour though.

Comment: @julesjacobs: Yes, I like your idea. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of doing it. There's a version of `Max` that takes no criterion, and uses `IComparable`. So we could provide a way to wrap anything in a comparable object, with a delegate providing the comparison.

```
public class Comparable<T> : IComparable<Comparable<T>>
{
    private readonly T _value;
    private readonly Func<T, T, int> _compare;

    public Comparable(T v, Func<T, T, int> compare)
    {
        _value = v;
        _compare = compare;
    }

    public T Value { get { return _value; } }

    public int CompareTo(Comparable<T> other)
    {
        return _compare(_value, other._value);
    }
}
```

Then we can say:

```
Model maxModel = models.Select(m => new Comparable<Model>(m, (a, b) => a.Name.Length - b.Name.Length)).Max().Value;
```

This involves a lot of extra allocation, but it's sort of academically interesting (I think).

Comment: Someone once told me "a delegate is the same as an interface with only one member".  You're basically making an Adapater between Func<T, T, int> and IComparable.  I like it.  The allocation cost isn't serious: it's not big, and the GC can handle the cleanup.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated it to use the generic IComparable which gets rid of the cast. Regarding delegates and one-member interfaces, check out http://tronicek.blogspot.com/2007/12/closure-conversion.html - he discusses this aspect in a proposed Java lauguage feature.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything gained by using the extension methods?

Perhaps a method or procedure with a simple iteration of the list would suffice?

Something to the effect of

```
Dim result as string = models(0).Name
for each m as Model in models
  if m.Name.length > result.length then
    result = m.Name
  end if
next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aggregate. It can be done without writing new extension method.

```
models.Aggregate(
                new KeyValuePair<Model, int>(),
                (a, b) => (a.Value < b.Name.Length) ? new KeyValuePair<Model, int>(b, b.Name.Length) : a,
                a => a.Key);
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way might be:

```
var item = (from m in models select m orderby m.Name.Length descending).FirstOrDefault();
```

First one will be the one with the longest length.

Comment: This requires buffering the whole stream, and sorting - O(n log n) for a fundamentally O(n) operation.

Comment: To put it another way: Max() only requires sorting the first element, but your algorithm requires sorting all elements.