# getting the best record from a file

Tags: c#

I have a file with the following text inside

```
mimi,m,70
tata,f,60
bobo,m,100
soso,f,30
```

I did the reading from file thing and many many other methods and functions, but how I can get the best male name and his grade according to the grade.

here is the code I wrote. Hope it's not so long

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace practice_Ex
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int[] ReadFile(string FileName, out string[] Name, out char[] Gender)
        {
            Name = new string[1];
            int[] Mark = new int[1];
            Gender = new char[1];
            if (File.Exists(FileName))
            {
                FileStream Input = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(Input);
                string[] Current;
                int Counter = 0;
                string Str = SR.ReadLine();
                while (Str != null)
                {
                    Current = Str.Split(',');
                    Name[Counter] = Current[0];
                    Mark[Counter] = int.Parse(Current[2]);
                    Gender[Counter] = char.Parse(Current[1].ToUpper());
                    Counter++;
                    Array.Resize(ref Name, Counter + 1);
                    Array.Resize(ref Mark, Counter + 1);
                    Array.Resize(ref Gender, Counter + 1);
                    Str = SR.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            return Mark;
        }

        public static int MostFreq(int[] M, out int Frequency)
        {
            int Counter = 0;
            int Frequent = 0;
            Frequency = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < M.Length; i++)
            {
                Counter = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < M.Length; j++)
                    if (M[i] == M[j])
                        Counter++;
                if (Counter > Frequency)
                {
                    Frequency = Counter;
                    Frequent = M[i];
                }
            }
            return Frequent;
        }

        public static int Avg(int[] M)
        {
            int total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < M.Length; i++)
                total += M[i];
            return total / M.Length;
        }

        public static int AvgCond(char[] G, int[] M, char S)
        {
            int total = 0;
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < G.Length; i++)
                if (G[i] == S)
                {
                    total += M[i];
                    counter++;
                }
            return total / counter;
        }

        public static int BelowAvg(int[] M, out int AboveAvg)
        {
            int Bcounter = 0;
            AboveAvg = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < M.Length; i++)
            {
                if (M[i] < Avg(M))
                    Bcounter++;
                else
                    AboveAvg++;
            }
            return Bcounter;
        }

        public static int CheckNames(string[] Name, char C)
        {
            C = char.Parse(C.ToString().ToLower());
            int counter = 0;
            string Str;
            for (int i = 0; i < Name.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                Str = Name[i].ToLower();
                if (Str[0] == C || Str[Str.Length - 1] == C)
                    counter++;
            }
            return counter;
        }

        public static void WriteFile(string FileName, string[] Output)
        {
            FileStream FS = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(FS);
            for (int i = 0; i < Output.Length; i++)
                SW.WriteLine(Output[i]);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] Mark;
            char[] Gender;
            string[] Name;
            string[] Output = new string[8];
            int Frequent, Frequency, AvgAll, MaleAvg, FemaleAvg, BelowAverage, AboveAverage, NamesCheck;
            Mark = ReadFile("c:\\IUST1.txt", out Name, out Gender);
            Frequent = MostFreq(Mark, out Frequency);
            AvgAll = Avg(Mark);
            MaleAvg = AvgCond(Gender, Mark, 'M');
            FemaleAvg = AvgCond(Gender, Mark, 'F');
            BelowAverage = BelowAvg(Mark, out AboveAverage);
            NamesCheck = CheckNames(Name, 'T');
            Output [0]= "Frequent Mark = " + Frequent.ToString();
            Output [1]= "Frequency = " + Frequency.ToString();
            Output [2]= "Average Of All = " + AvgAll.ToString();
            Output [3]= "Average Of Males = " + MaleAvg.ToString();
            Output [4]= "Average Of Females = " + FemaleAvg.ToString();
            Output [5]= "Below Average = " + BelowAverage.ToString();
            Output [6]= "Above Average = " + AboveAverage.ToString();
            Output [7]= "Names With \"T\" = " + NamesCheck.ToString();
            WriteFile("c:\\Output.txt", Output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, that amount of Array.Resize is going to cripple performance; List<T> etc is preferred here.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I like LINQ (update: excluded via comments) for querying, especially if I can do it without buffering the data (so I can process a huge file efficiently). For example below (update: removed LINQ); note the use of iterator blocks (`yield return`) makes this fully "lazy" - only one record is held in memory at a time.

This also shows separation of concerns: one method deals with reading a file line by line; one method deals with parsing a line into a typed data record; one (or more) method(s) work with those data record(s).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

enum Gender { Male, Female, Unknown }
class Record
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
static class Program
{
    static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string path)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(path))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                yield return line;
            }
        }
    }
    static IEnumerable<Record> Parse(string path)
    {
        foreach (string line in ReadLines(path))
        {
            string[] segments = line.Split(',');
            Gender gender;
            switch(segments[1]) {
                case "m": gender = Gender.Male; break;
                case "f": gender = Gender.Female; break;
                default: gender = Gender.Unknown; break;
            }
            yield return new Record
            {
                Name = segments[0],
                Gender = gender,
                Score = int.Parse(segments[2])
            };
        }
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        Record best = null;
        foreach (Record record in Parse("data.txt"))
        {
            if (record.Gender != Gender.Male) continue;
            if (best == null || record.Score > best.Score)
            {
                best = record;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", best.Name, best.Score);
    }
}
```

The advantage of writing things as iterators is that you can easily use either streaming or buffering - for example, you can do:

```
List<Record> data = new List<Record>(Parse("data.txt"));
```

and then manipulate `data` all day long (assuming it isn't too large) - useful for multiple aggregates, mutating data, etc.

Comment: im not in Linq yet i dont know how to use it so can u keep it simple and basic as the code i wrote thanx marc

Comment: OK, I'll remove the LINQ bits - about 2 lines ;-p

Comment: ben: I would *strongly* encourage you to use this problem as an entry point into LINQ. It's the kind of thing LINQ excels at. Sure, use a non-LINQ way for the moment, but come back soon with a LINQ book to hand, and weep for the beauty of it all :)

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384633/select-the-maximal-item-from-collection-by-some-criterion) asks how to find a maximal element by a certain criterion. Combine that with Marc's LINQ part and you're away.

Answer (score 1):

In the real world, of course, these would be records in a database, and you would use one line of SQL to select the best record, ie:

SELECT Name, Score FROM Grades WHERE Score = MAX(Score)

(This returns more than one record where there's more than one best record, of course.)  This is an example of the power of using the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest and least-code way would be to transform the txt to xml and then use Linq2Xml to select from it. [Here's a link.](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx)

Edit: That might be more work than you'd like to do. Another option is to create a class called AcademicRecord that has properties for the persons name gender etc. Then when you read the file, add to a List for each line in the file. Then use a Sort predicate to sort the list; the highest record would then be the first one in the list. [Here's a link.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ASPNet_Sorting.aspx)

Comment: Added a solution using Generics, which will be a really handy thing for you to learn. And will cut down on your code significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment might have different requirements, but if you only want to get "best male name and grade" from a file you described, a compact way is:

```
public String FindRecord()
{
    String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("MyFile.csv");
    Array.Sort(lines, CompareByBestMaleName);
    return lines[0];
}

int SortByBestMaleName(String a, String b)
{
    String[] ap = a.Split();            
    String[] bp = b.Split();
     // Always rank male higher
    if (ap[1] == "m" && bp[1] == "f") { return 1; }
    if (ap[1] == "f" && bp[1] == "m") { return -1; }
    // Compare by score
    return int.Parse(ap[2]).CompareTo(int.Parse(bp[2]));
}
```

Note that this is neither fast nor robust.