# Larger File Streams using C#

Tags: c#, filestream

There are some text files(Records) which i need to access using C#.Net. But the matter is those files are larger than 1GB. (minimum size is 1 GB)

what should I need to do?
What are the factors which I need to be concentrate on?

Can some one give me an idea to over come from this situation.

EDIT:

Thanks for the fast responses. yes they are fixed length records. These text files coming from a local company. (There last month transaction records)

Is it possible to access these files like normal text files (using normal file stream).

and

How about the memory management????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on CasperOne's answer

Simply put there is no way to reliably put a 100GB file into memory at one time.  On a 32 bit machine there is simply not enough addressing space.  In a 64 bit machine there is enough addressing space but during the time in which it would take to actually get the file in memory, your user will have killed your process out of frustration.

The trick is to process the file incrementally.  The base System.IO.Stream() class is designed to process a variable (and possibly infinite) stream in distinct quantities.  It has several Read methods that will only progress down a stream a specific number of bytes.  You will need to use these methods in order to divide up the stream.

I can't give more information because your scenario is not specific enough.  Can you give us more details or your record delimeters or some sample lines from the file?

**Update**

If they are fixed length records then System.IO.Stream will work just fine.  You can even use File.Open() to get access to the underlying Stream object.  Stream.Read has an overload that requests the number of bytes to be read from the file.  Since they are fixed length records this should work well for your scenario.

As long as you don't call ReadAllText() and instead use the Stream.Read() methods which take explicit byte arrays, memory won't be an issue.  The underlying Stream class will take care not to put the entire file into memory (that is of course, unless you ask it to :) ).

Answer (score 1):

You aren't specifically listing the problems you need to overcome.  A file can be 100GB and you can have no problems processing it.

If you have to process the file *as a whole* then that is going to require some creative coding, but if you can simply process sections of the file at a time, then it is relatively easy to move to the location in the file you need to start from, process the data you need to process in chunks, and then close the file.

More information here would certainly be helpful.

Comment: Exactly what Casper said, also, are they fixed length records, or variable length and delimted by new lines?

Answer (score 0):

What are the main problems you are having at the moment? The big thing to remember is to think in terms of streams - i.e. keep the minimum amount of data in memory that you can. LINQ is excellent at working with sequences (although there are some buffering operations you need to avoid, such as OrderBy).

For example, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417878/getting-the-best-record-from-a-file#417932) a way of handling simple records from a large file efficiently (note the iterator block).

For performing multiple aggregates/analysis over large data from files, consider [Push LINQ](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/01/04/quot-push-quot-linq-revisited-next-attempt-at-an-explanation.aspx) in [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/).

Can you add more context to the problems you are thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on JaredPar's answer.

If the file is a binary file (i.e. ints stored as 4 bytes, fixed length strings etc) you can use the BinaryReader class. Easier than pulling out n bytes and then trying to interrogate that.

Also note, the read method on System.IO.Stream is a non blocking operation. If you ask for 100 bytes it may return less than that, but still not have reached end of file.

The BinaryReader.ReadBytes method will block until it reads the requested number of bytes, or End of file - which ever comes first.

Nice collaboration lads :)

Comment: Should we ask for a group answer feature ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys, I realize that this post hasn't been touched in a while, but I just wanted to post a site that has the solution to your problem.

http://thedeveloperpage.wordpress.com/c-articles/using-file-streams-to-write-any-size-file-introduction/

Hope it helps!

-CJ